# Parse.com SDK file not Found in XCode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm currently using Cocoapods to install Parse.com's SDK on my project.  Everything was working until today when I suddenly received an error: `Unknown Type Name: 'PFImageView', did you mean 'UIImageView?'`.

This obviously represents a problem for me as there are a lot of underlying functions in the Parse SDK that I depend on.

Notably; the framework itself can be found just fine and I have no issue trying to build queries or getting anything to autocomplete, but whenever there's anything with `PFImageView` involved it says it can't be found.

Did something change recently with the Parse.com SDK?

Comment: Yes, did u get the latest Parse SDK version?

Comment: Yeah I just did `pod update`.  What changed?

Comment: Edit to above:  I read the change log but didn't see anything that might affect this.  I made sure I used the most recent sdk.  Switching branches doesn't help either.  Could it be something in derived data?  I cleared the folder out but don't know if that would help.

Comment: Is it happening for every PFImageView reference you have or just one in specific?

Comment: Nope, every instance in every relevant file is showing the same set of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally.  After chasing which frameworks and pods to add to the project to get it to build correctly, it seems that the Parse IOS SDK version was the culprit.  I forced it down to `1.8.5` vs. `9.0` and the problem went away.  Checking the Github repo apparently this is an issue that they're aware of and a lot of people had to force 1.8.5 in order to get it to work properly.

Link in case anyone else stumbles on this:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-iOS/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because ParseUI framework is a separate entity. You need to add `pod 'ParseUI'` to your `podfile`

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/README.md

Comment: How many pod files do I have to add for the Parse SDK??? Every time I add another pod like `Parse`, `ParseUI`, `ParseFacebookUtils` there's another error.  It never ends!